# Pose change is not permanent

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am changing the pose using R to rotate the model's arms.
It works, but as soon as I scrub the timeline, the change is undone.

How do I make it permanent? I thought it would automatically be applied to the selected keyframe.

Thank you!

[Video of the failure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5JdrNExZnI)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender has no reason to take the rotation you've made into account as you've not saved it with an *Insert Keyframe* (shortcut <kbd>i</kbd>).

If you want any transform to be automatically saved without the need of *Insert Keyframe*, you need to enable the *Auto Keying* option in the *Timeline*:

[image]

If you enable its *Only Active Keying Set* option, it will only take the selected transform into account:

[image]

Comment: You are so helpful, thank you!!!